# Order by decreasing order across multiple variables for ggplot2's geom_errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

```
library(ggplot2)
mydat <- data.frame(mean = c(23, 24, 15, 27, 18, 19, 23, 20, 32),
           lower = c(20, 19, 13, 15, 14, 18, 20, 17, 20),
           upper = c(25, 29, 17, 39, 22, 20, 26, 23, 40),
           class = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
           domain = c("North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", "South", "South", "South"))
mydat$class <- as.factor(mydat$class)
mydat$domain <- as.factor(mydat$domain)

mydat %>% ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = class, color = domain, Group = domain, xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + theme_light() + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + xlab("Counts")
```

[image]

I would like to order by decreasing value of the upper bounds (i.e., `upper`) of the error bar both within each `class` and also across `domain`s. The desired output is this:

[image]

I tried the following code but it didn't have the desired effect:

```
library(forcats)
mydat %>% ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = class, color = fct_infreq(domain), Group = fct_infreq(domain), xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + theme_light() + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + xlab("Counts")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an 'easy' way to achieve that outcome; when you reorder your y-axis according to `max(upper)` the order is 'set' for all domains (although I would be happy to be proven wrong on this).

One potential work-around might be to split up your plots by class and reorder each one separately, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydat <- data.frame(mean = c(23, 24, 15, 27, 18, 19, 23, 20, 32),
                    lower = c(20, 19, 13, 15, 14, 18, 20, 17, 20),
                    upper = c(25, 29, 17, 39, 22, 20, 26, 23, 40),
                    class = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                    domain = c("North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", "South", "South", "South"))
mydat$class <- as.factor(mydat$class)
mydat$domain <- as.factor(mydat$domain)

colour_palette <- scales::hue_pal()(3)

mydat %>%
  group_split(class) %>%
  map(~{ggplot(data = .x,
               aes(x = mean, y = fct_reorder(.f = class, .x = upper, .fun = max),
                   color = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
                   Group = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
                   xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
      xlab("Counts") +
      ylab("Class") +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("North" = colour_palette[1],
                                    "South" = colour_palette[2],
                                    "West" = colour_palette[3]),
                         name = "Domain")})
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

If you do this 'manually' you can then arrange them in your desired order, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydat <- data.frame(mean = c(23, 24, 15, 27, 18, 19, 23, 20, 32),
                    lower = c(20, 19, 13, 15, 14, 18, 20, 17, 20),
                    upper = c(25, 29, 17, 39, 22, 20, 26, 23, 40),
                    class = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                    domain = c("North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", "South", "South", "South"))
mydat$class <- as.factor(mydat$class)
mydat$domain <- as.factor(mydat$domain)

colour_palette <- scales::hue_pal()(3)

p1 <- mydat %>%
  filter(class == "A") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = fct_reorder(.f = class, .x = upper, .fun = max),
                   color = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
                   Group = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
                   xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
      geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
      theme_light(base_size = 18) + 
      geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
      xlab("") +
      ylab("") +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("North" = colour_palette[1],
                                    "South" = colour_palette[2],
                                    "West" = colour_palette[3]),
                         name = "Domain") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 45))

p2 <- mydat %>%
  filter(class == "B") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = fct_reorder(.f = class, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             color = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             Group = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  theme_light(base_size = 18) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  xlab("Counts") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("North" = colour_palette[1],
                                "South" = colour_palette[2],
                                "West" = colour_palette[3]),
                     name = "Domain") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 45))

p3 <- mydat %>%
  filter(class == "C") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = fct_reorder(.f = class, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             color = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             Group = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  theme_light(base_size = 18) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("North" = colour_palette[1],
                                "South" = colour_palette[2],
                                "West" = colour_palette[3]),
                     name = "Domain") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10, 45))

library(patchwork)
p3 / p1 / p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I also think that it seems impossible to achieve exactly the same output as requested, and your facet-style should be a more reasonable way to visualize it. +1!

Comment: @jared_marmrot Thanks for your answer. A follow-up question: is it possible to re-order the labels under "Domain"? I.e., instead of "North, South, West", can we have "South", "West", "North"? I tried changing the order using `scale_color_manual(values = ...)` but it didn't seem to affect the ordering.

Comment: If you specify breaks in your `scale_color_manual()` (e.g. breaks = c("South", "West", "North")) it should change the order @Adrian

Answer (score 1):

I cannot figure out the same output as you expected, but hope the following code makes sense to you equivalently (where `domain` info is added as labels to each errorbar)

```
mydat %>%
    mutate(class = factor(class, names(sort(by(upper, class, max))))) %>%
    arrange(class, desc(upper)) %>%
    mutate(color = factor(n() - row_number()), .by = class) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = class, color = color, Group = domain, xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
    geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = domain), position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
    theme_light() +
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    xlab("Counts")
```

[image]

## Data

```
mydat <- data.frame(
    mean = c(23, 24, 15, 27, 18, 19, 23, 20, 32),
    lower = c(20, 19, 13, 15, 14, 18, 20, 17, 20),
    upper = c(25, 29, 17, 39, 22, 20, 26, 23, 40),
    class = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
    domain = c("North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", "South", "South", "South")
)
```